# Memory efficient way of converting raw image data into features for a neural net

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, google-cloud-platform, keras

I'm working on a machine learning problem and one of the first steps in my pipeline is to convert the raw data into features. Since I'm working with very large datasets I constantly run into memory issues. These are the steps I follow - I'd like to know if there are some things that are fundamentally wrong with the approach. For context, I'm working with 10,000s of images on a Google Cloud machine with 64GB ram.

**1 - Create array to store features**

Create numpy array to store the features. Example below is for a feature array that will hold 14,000 image features, each of which has height/width of 288/512 and 3 color channels).

```
x = np.zeros((14000, 288, 512, 3)) # 29316
```

**2 - Read in raw images sequentially, process them, and put them into x**

```
for idx, name in enumerate(raw_data_paths):
    image = functions.read_png(name)
    features = get_feature(image)
    x[idx] = features
```

**3 - train/test split**

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=test_fraction, random_state=42)
```

---

**Questions**

1. **Am I approaching this completely incorrectly by using numpy arrays when there are more efficient storage mechanisms?** I need to later use the data on a Keras neural net so working with numpy arrays has been convenient.
2. I tend to get issues with step (1) and step (3) above. For step 1, I sometimes cannot execute that line because I run out of memory. Interestingly, I have no issues on my slow local computer (which I'm guessing is using virtual memory), but I do get issues on my Linux Google Compute instance which has 64GB memory. **How can I fix this issue?**
3. For step (3) I sometimes run out of memory, and I imagine it's because when that line is executed I double memory needs (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test together I would imagine require as much memory as x and y). **Is there a way to do this step without doubling memory requirements?**

Comment: I feel like tasks of this size frequently go to a cloud - have you looked into spark?

Comment: I'm transferring the raw image files a Google cloud storage bucket and then doing the feature extraction there. So I'm already doing the task in the cloud. Is that what you mean?

I have not looked into Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - In keras, you can either use a python `generator` or a [keras sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) for training. You define then the size of the batches.

You will train your model using `fit_generator`, passing the generator or the sequence. Adjust the parameters `max_queue_size` to at most 1 (the queue will be loaded in parallel while the model works on a batch)

2 - Do you really need to work with 14000 at once? Can't you make smaller batches?

You may use `np.empty` instead of `np.zeros`.

3 - Splitting train and test data is just as easy as:

```
trainData = originalData[:someSize]    
testData = originalData[somesize:]
```

---

**Using generators or sequences**

These are options for you to load your data in parts, and you can define these parts any way you want.

You can indeed save your data in smaller files to load each file per step. 
Or you can also do the entire image preprocessing inside the generator, in small batches.

See this answer for a simple example of a generator: [Training a Keras model on multiple feature files that are read in sequentially to save memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229966/training-a-keras-model-on-multiple-feature-files-that-are-read-in-sequentially-t/46230003#46230003)

You can create a generator from a list of image files, divide the list in batches of files, and at each step, do the preprocessing:

```
def loadInBatches(batchSize,dataPaths):

    while True:
        for step in range(0,len(dataPaths),batchSize):

            x = np.empty((batchSize, 288, 512, 3)) 
            y = np.empty(???)

            for idx,name in enumerate(dataPaths[step:step+batchSize])

                image = functions.read_png(name)
                features = get_feature(image)
                x[idx] = features
                y[idx] = ???

            yield (x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks. I can definitely work with less than 14,000 at once. To be clear, are you suggesting then to save multiple x's then (x1_train, x2_train, x3_train, etc.)? Hoes does have multiple feature *files* work together with the generators in keras?

Comment: You can do that, and at each step you load one file. It's an option, but it will consume an enormous amount of storage. Or you can simply not have any numpy files, just the images, and load and preprocess the images in small amounts. Create little numpy arrays at each step. See updates in answer.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Ty!

Comment: @megashigger Also you can use `uint8` data type for the numpy arrays. It'll result in 8x smaller memory/storage usage than numpy's default `float64`. 14000 images should be okay for 64GB ram if you use `uint8`. You can convert a batch of images back to `float32` in data generator before feeding them into your Keras network.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution, which can solve all the 3 question (more or less), is to use Tensorflow. The latter gives the possibility to create a queue of input. You can find more information in [Threading and Queues](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues). This is easy to use way to scale your training.

Since you wanna later on use Neural Net, I suggest you to spend sometimes to learn TF, and the queues, since they are a very powerfull tool.